# Does the hadith describing "benevolent love towards people" exist?

Tags: hadith, source-identification, authenticity

Does this hadith exist? What is its source?

> The Prophet Muhammad (peace be upon him) taught us that the best deed after believing there is no deity worthy of worship except God is "benevolent love towards people".
>
> The Arabic is al-tawaddudu ila al-nas.  Which literally means love towards the people/humanity.
>
> [Reference: Tabarani.  Graded: Hasan]

This was posted by Hamza A. Tzortzis on [Twitter](https://twitter.com/HATzortzis/status/774599496839925763).